# ARToolKit Custom camera tracking area

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, artoolkit

Iam making an iOS app using ARToolKit, everything is working fine. But my tracking objects are so close to each other , therefore most of the time it tracks most accurate tracking pattern and hard to focus on others.  Is there a way to give a size or specify an area which the ARcamera should track ? something like 200px square area from centre of the AR camera to track. if so other camera area will not focus on tracking.  Is there a way or any idea?

Comment: Are you having issues with camera autofocus, or marker tracking region? If marker tracking region, why constrain where you wish to track on screen?

Comment: i want to make a custom tracking region, then i can ignore the other tracking patterns around the AR camera view, because my trackers located so close to each other. @WallyYoung

Answer (score 1):

ARToolKit will process the video feed you supply it (via the libARVideo library). I would recommend having it process the whole video feed and only choosing to act on the markers you wish to use, not constraining the area of tracking. Otherwise, you can post-process the video feed to constrain to your desired dimensions.